# CGEventTap making NSEvent of CGEvent deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, nsevent, cgeventtap

I'm using an EventTap, and i need to set the pressure of my CGEvent in code (i'm making a pressure averaging app).

For now I don't see any other way than to transform my CGEvent into an NSEvent to change the pressure. The problem now is that once in a while i'm getting "deallocated instance errors" and my app crashes. I'm using ARC. I used Zombie Instrument to track down the issue. Here's a screenshot of the Instrument. Clearly, somewhere either the CGEvent or the NSEvent is getting a release message but it is already released. I have no idea how i can have more control over this releasing process... :(.

Here's the code I use in the handleCGEvent method

```
CGEventRef handleCGEvent(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type,     CGEventRef eventRef, void *refcon)
{
    if(type == kCGEventLeftMouseDragged)
    {
        NSEvent *wacomEvent = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:eventRef];

    if (wacomEvent != nil && wacomEvent.subtype == NSTabletPointEventSubtype)
    {
        [pressureBuffer replaceObjectAtIndex:pressureBufferIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: wacomEvent.pressure]];
        pressureBufferIndex++;
        pressureBufferIndex %= pressureBufferSize;

        if (pressureBufferFilledCount < pressureBufferSize)
            pressureBufferFilledCount++;

        float sum = 0;

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < pressureBufferFilledCount; i++)
        {
            sum += [[pressureBuffer objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        }

        averagePressure = sum / pressureBufferFilledCount;

        NSEvent *newPressureEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:wacomEvent.type
                                                       location:wacomEvent.locationInWindow
                                                  modifierFlags:wacomEvent.modifierFlags
                                                      timestamp:wacomEvent.timestamp
                                                   windowNumber:wacomEvent.windowNumber
                                                        context:wacomEvent.context
                                                    eventNumber:wacomEvent.eventNumber
                                                     clickCount:wacomEvent.clickCount
                                                       pressure:averagePressure]; //averagePressure

        return [newPressureEvent CGEvent];
    }
}

return eventRef;
}
```

....

Thanks, any help much appreciated!!!!

[image: screenshot of zombie instrument !!!]

Comment: You clearly have not shown not the whole code for `handleCGEvent`. Show the rest of it, including its signature. You should be able to get Instruments to show you the actual line of the autorelease it's doing. Where is that?

Comment: @KenThomases I edited my question so now the whole handleCGEvent is included. I don't know what you mean with the actual line of the autorelease? this is everything zombie instruments shows me... I cannot click on anything to get me to a specific line of code. Also : the crash happens mostly when changing the focus of the display to a secondary screen. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why don't you do `CGEventSetDoubleValueField(eventRef, kCGTabletEventPointPressure, averagePressure)`?

Comment: @Willeke must have skipped over that method :O. This fixed it! Eternal thank you's!

Comment: @Willeke why is the printed value between 0 and 2.0 when i'm doing    NSLog(@"PRESSURE: %f",CGEventGetDoubleValueField(eventRef, kCGTabletEventPointPressure));
? It should be between 0.0 and 1.0 right? thnx!

Comment: Perhaps no longer relevant, but you should be able to show the stack trace of the Autorelease line by switching to the Extended Detail inspector. And it should take you to a line of code by double-clicking the appropriate stack frame.

Comment: Read [Bug in CGEventSetDoubleValueField function with scaled fields](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/May/msg00063.html) and the reply.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke!, using CGEventSetIntegerValueField solved the problem.